# How do we do the android call by clicking on TextView?

Tags: android

i am getting some issues after clicking on TextView for getting call from android .Can anybody suggest me why..Thganks

My Code:

```
public void goForTheCall() {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(helpDesk));
    startActivity(callIntent);

}
```

On startaActivity,**It is showing error in red like "Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`**" 
And my manifestfile

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: show your text view xml code here

Comment: or are you testing it emulator?

Comment: You need to implement [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) if you are testing on Android M+.

Comment: <TextView
        android:text="@string/call_help_desk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/call_nissan_helpDesk"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Nissan.Bold.H2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/how_can_we_help_you" />@xFighter

Comment: Try to edit and paste this code in the question

Comment: No..i am using Android device 5.0.2 @xFighter

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with Android 6 requesting permissions at runtime. So you should be following the tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) on developer.android.com.

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Comment: But i am using Android Lolipop@Monica

Comment: @VikashKumar Use `try {} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.e("PERMISSION_EXCEPTION","PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED");
}`, but the code above (in my answer) is backward compatible so you should use it for API 23 & below.

Answer (score 0):

please check for a marshmallow runtime permissions. if you denied the permission then you have to goto settings and turn on the permissions.

```
int checkPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
    if (checkPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                        REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
            } else {
                customDialog(CallChoosyActivity.this);
            }
```